# How to parse HTML article by its section id (tags) in R

Tags: html, r, parsing

I am trying to parse Pubmed Central articles in HTML format. I want to extract the each section separately. For example, abstract, introduction, result, etc.

Example:

```
doc.html = htmlTreeParse(paste("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/",2242602,"/", sep=""), useInternal = FALSE)

doc.html
```

Gives the following:

```
<div id="sec1" class="tsec sec">
<h2 class="head no_bottom_margin" id="sec1title">1. Introduction</h2>
<p id="__p4" class="p p-first-last">In an effort to extend the structural coverage of proteins for which the biological function is unknown and cannot be deduced by homology, domain of unknown function (DUF) targets were selected from Pfam protein family PF01796 (DUF35). Here, we report the crystal structure of SSO2064, the first structural representative of this family, which was determined using the semiautomated high-throughput pipeline of the Joint Center for Structural Genomics (JCSG; <a href="http://www.jcsg.org" ref="reftype=extlink&amp;article-id=2954200&amp;issue-id=190704&amp;journal-id=381&amp;FROM=Article%7CBody&amp;TO=External%7CLink%7CURI&amp;rendering-type=normal" target="pmc_ext">http://www.jcsg.org</a>; Lesley <em>et al.</em>, 2002<a href="#bb31" rid="bb31" class=" bibr popnode tag_hotlink tag_tooltip" id="__tag_198914221"> ▶</a>) as part of the National Institute of General Medical Sciences (NIGMS) Protein Structure Initiative (PSI). The <em>SSO2064</em> gene of <em>Sulfolobus solfataricus</em>, a hyperthermoacidophilic crenarchaeon (She <em>et al.</em>, 2001<a href="#bb38" rid="bb38" class=" bibr popnode tag_hotlink tag_tooltip" id="__tag_300464760"> ▶</a>), encodes a protein with a molecular weight of 16.5 kDa (residues 1–144) and a calculated isoelectric point of 6.6. Structural analysis of SSO2064 revealed two N-terminal helices followed by a rubredoxin-like zinc ribbon and an oligonucletide/oligosaccharide-binding (OB) fold domain; the genome context and operon organization suggest a role in lipid and polyketide antibiotic biosynthesis.</p>

<div id="sec2" class="tsec sec">
<h2 class="head no_bottom_margin" id="sec2title">2. Materials and methods</h2>
<h3>2.1. Protein production and crystallization</h3>     
<p id="__p5" class="p p-first-last"> Clones were generated using the Polymerase Incomplete Primer</p>
```

I want to extract **Introduction** and **Material and Methods** sections separately using their sec ids.

I can do the following for sec1:

```
id_or_class_xp <- "//div[@id='__sec1']"
doc = htmlParse(xpathSApply( doc.html,id_or_class_xp,xmlValue), asText=TRUE)
fullTextSection <- as.String(xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue))
```

Since I don't know the exact number of sections in an article, is there a way to extract each section by its sec id, for example within a loop?

Comment: You could try `id_or_class_xp <- "//div[starts-with(@id, '__sec')]"`.

Comment: @lukeA I think it finds the sections but it prints nothing. 

`id_or_class_xp <- "//div[starts-with(@id, '__sec')]"`

`htmlParse(xpathSApply( doc.html,id_or_class_xp), asText=TRUE)`
`<html><body><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:><pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></pointer:></body></html>`

Comment: `doc <- htmlParse(paste("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/",2242602,"/", sep="")); xpathSApply(doc, "//div[starts-with(@id, '__sec')]", xmlValue)`

Comment: That worked, thanks!